# Why is my jQuery not detecting a click on an <i> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, onclick, click

```js
$('.close_cart').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).find('.btn_container').remove();
});
```

```css
.btn_container .btn_cart .close_cart {
  opacity: 0.8;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

.btn_container .btn_cart .close_cart:before {
  content: "";
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url(https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/43730af340cb0a2cc17396e3001a86ac?s=256&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 3.25px;
  right: 3px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn_container">
  <a class="btn_cart" title="Aaaaa" href="#">
        Aaaaa
        <i class="close_cart"></i>
    </a>
</div>
```

The above jQuery code is somehow not working. I have checked the console and I get no error message. The jQuery code is loading. I think this problem is probably caused by the pseudo-element. I've realised the :before makes my  tag not have any width, however, I've manually added width and a display:block on the  tag and I'm still not getting any response. It's obvious that I'm doing something wrong but I can't seem to see what is it. Help please! Thank you :D

Comment: at a guess the `.close_cart` element has no physical size and `pseudo` elements do not receive events

Comment: please focus on your before, seems `before` is not working now

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius In the description, I specify that "I've manually added width and a display:block on the <i> tag and I'm still not getting any response".

Comment: @RomanGavrilov0 The :before is not being rendered by Stackoverflow.

Comment: The code had a few issues, with some introduced to make it ready for the demo. I updated my answer, let me know :)

Answer (score 1):

Steps to make it work:

1. Added an image that works here
2. Added `display: block;`
3. Removed `position: absolute;`
4. Removed `.cart` class as it's not in the demo HTML.

```js
$('.close_cart').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("Hello");
});
```

```css
.cart .btn_container .btn_cart .close_cart {
  opacity: 0.8;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

.btn_container .btn_cart .close_cart:before {
  content: '';
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url(https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/43730af340cb0a2cc17396e3001a86ac?s=256&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1);
  top: 3.25px;
  right: 3px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn_container">
  <a class="btn_cart" title="Aaaaa" href="#">
        Aaaaa
        <i class="close_cart"></i>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! However, I can't listen to clicks on .btn_Cart because it contains more elements (I simplified it for the question) and it would affect those elements too. I also can't put content inside close_cart because it's meant to only have an icon in it's :before, nothing more. Isn't there any solution that doesn't involve listening to other elements or putting content inside? Thank you!

Comment: At the current state, the `i` element is something that takes no space in the page, so you cannot click on it. If in your case it has an icon, please update the question :)

Comment: In the description, I specify that "I've manually added width and a display:block on the <i> tag and I'm still not getting any response".

Comment: I updated my answer :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you're are the one that has helped me the most by far. However it's still not working. I've updated the question with the demo mistakes you pointed out.

Note: I've realised that if I select .btn_card instead of .close_cart in jQuery, I'm still not getting a response. However, if I select an element one level above .btn_card, it works.

Comment: I still see position: absolute in the question.

Comment: Position: absolute is not a demo mistake, it is needed.

Answer (score 0):

In order to actually have your code successfully close your cart, you need to implement that functionality in your code.

Right now, your click function does nothing but log "Hello" to the console.

You could use the jquery .hide() function to hide the cart (https://api.jquery.com/hide/).

The code below would hide the HTML element with id="cart" upon click.

```js
$('.close_cart').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#cart').hide();
    console.log("Hello");
});
```

```css
.cart .btn_container .btn_cart .close_cart {
    opacity: 0.8;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left: 1rem;
}
.cart .btn_container .btn_cart .close_cart:before {
    content: "";
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url(../_img/close.png);
    position: absolute;
    top: 3.25px;
    right: 3px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cart">
  <div class="btn_container">
      <a class="btn_cart" title="Aaaaa" href="#">
          Aaaaa
          <i class="close_cart">x</i>
      </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's an example... I've edited so you can see I actually have a .remove()... The problem is that click function is not triggering.